# How do I get an Airprint working with my printer?

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can share my printer so that I can use it with Airprint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26130/how-can-share-my-printer-so-that-i-can-use-it-with-airprint)

I have a Brother MFC 260C and am trying to get Airprint and ios 5.01 to print from ipad 2
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't have time to write this out, but if someone is interested in free rep, the answer is here - https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-June/033611.html

Comment: @jrg Shouldn't it be sufficient to post an answer that contains that link and explains in one sentence or so what it is?

Comment: @eliahkagan Alright, I'll do that. :P